# Django ORM queryset equivalent to group by year-month?

Tags: django, group-by, django-queryset, aggregation

I have an Django app and need some datavisualization and I am blocked with ORM.

I have a models Orders with a field created_at and I want to present data with a diagram bar (number / year-month) in a dashboard template.
So I need to aggregate/annotate data from my model but did find a complete solution.

I find partial answer with TruncMonth and read about serializers but wonder if there is a simpliest solution with Django ORM possibilities...

In Postgresql it would be:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month',created_at), count(order_id) FROM "Orders" GROUP BY date_trunc('month',created_at) ORDER BY date_trunc('month',created_at);

"2021-01-01 00:00:00+01"    "2"
"2021-02-01 00:00:00+01"    "3"
"2021-03-01 00:00:00+01"    "3"
...
```

example

```
1   "2021-01-04 07:42:03+01"
2   "2021-01-24 13:59:44+01"
3   "2021-02-06 03:29:11+01"
4   "2021-02-06 08:21:15+01"
5   "2021-02-13 10:38:36+01"
6   "2021-03-01 12:52:22+01"
7   "2021-03-06 08:04:28+01"
8   "2021-03-11 16:58:56+01"
9   "2022-03-25 21:40:10+01"
10  "2022-04-04 02:12:29+02"
11  "2022-04-13 08:24:23+02"
12  "2022-05-08 06:48:25+02"
13  "2022-05-19 15:40:12+02"
14  "2022-06-01 11:29:36+02"
15  "2022-06-05 02:15:05+02"
16  "2022-06-05 03:08:22+02"
```

expected result

```
[
    {
        "year-month": "2021-01",
        "number" : 2
    },
    {
        "year-month": "2021-03",
        "number" : 3
    },
    {
        "year-month": "2021-03",
        "number" : 3
    },
    {
        "year-month": "2021-03",
        "number" : 1
    },
    {
        "year-month": "2021-04",
        "number" : 2
    },
    {
        "year-month": "2021-05",
        "number" : 3
    },
    {
        "year-month": "2021-06",
        "number" : 3
    },
]
```

I have done this but I am not able to order by date:

```
Orders.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('created_at')).values('month').annotate(number=Count('order_id')).values('month', 'number').order_by()

<SafeDeleteQueryset [
   {'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'number': 4}, 
   {'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'number': 2}, 
   {'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'number': 1}, 
   {'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'number': 5}, 
   {'month': datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'number': 1}, 
   {'month': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'number': 1}, 
   {'month': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'number': 2}, 
   '...(remaining elements truncated)...'
]>
```

Comment: `order_by('month')` didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the order_by on the original field if you have multi-year data.

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth


Orders.objects.values(month=TruncMonth('created_at')).
    order_by("created_at").annotate(Sum('number')
```